# Is it just a coincidence that five Mulan movies were released in China this year?

Tags: mulan

For some reason, there are a lot of Mulan movies this year in China:

1. Matchless Mulan 无双花木兰 ([full movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Co5K-6xfx0g); [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12845320); [Douban](https://movie.douban.com/subject/34833858/)) which I don't think made it to the cinemas due to coronavirus; I can watch it on my internet TV.
2. Mulan 花木兰 ([trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KK8FHdFluOQ); [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4566758); [Douban](https://movie.douban.com/subject/26357307/)), the one by Disney, which is still on at the cinemas.
3. Kung Fu Mulan 木兰：横空出世 ([trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_i3q0OT2ac); [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11952874); [Douban](https://movie.douban.com/subject/34842226/)), an animation which was [reported as removed from cinemas](https://www.scmp.com/abacus/culture/article/3104700/chinas-own-kung-fu-mulan-takes-disney-and-becomes-another-2020-flop) due to poor reception (I can't find tickets on my phone).
4. 花木兰 ([Douban](https://movie.douban.com/subject/34800544/)) which I can watch on my TV.
5. The Heroine Mulan 木兰之巾帼英豪 ([full movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZQIk62n56k); [Douban](https://movie.douban.com/subject/34482017/)) seems to be a web movie.

I guess it could be a coincidence, or maybe there is an underlying reason.

**Question**: Is it just a coincidence that five Mulan movies were released in China this year?

Comment: My first instinct was that there was some copyright expiring but this doesn’t seem quite right considering how short the timeframe is: the most recent before was probably a [2009 Mulan movie](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1308138/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2).